# How to find all files containing a given file?

Tags: bash, unix, grep, find

I would want to find all files in a given directory that contain the entire content of a given file (not necessarily a text file).

I tried to achieve this goal through the use of `find` and `grep` but wasn't successful due to the search across several lines.

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have tried to solve your problem, please post your efforts along with the samples of input and output in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: I read that `grep` wasn't able to achieve multi-line search ; I could perhaps get the wanted result with a loop on the lines of my file. Maybe I could use `sed` to handle directly multi-line search (I am not familiar with it). Moreover, the manpage states that `grep` can handle binary files but, as far as I understand, the pattern is required to be a text string ; and besides, when trying it on a string extracted from my file, I get the following message : `grep: illegal byte sequence`. Which possibility should I explore ?

Comment: Please post sample of input and sample of expected output in your post and let us know then for better understanding of question.

Comment: Let `a` be a file containing a short one-line string extracted from the file. This is not a text file ; when typing `cat a` I get `?аOb?ƶ{?ـׅ`. And when performing `grep $(cat a) a`, the result is : `grep: illegal byte sequence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SearchBin" is a simple python script that can check if one file exists inside some others: https://github.com/Sepero/SearchBin

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 searchbin.py -f needle
```

where `needle` is the file whose contents are to be found.